# Trying to write a swap position function for a doubly linked list

Tags: python, swap, doubly-linked-list

I've been trying to create a simple linked list implementation in Python as a code exercise and, although I have most of the stuff working (inserting, removing, pretty print, swapping the content of two nodes), I've been stuck on swapping two nodes for a few days.

I've looked around on the internet and most people seem to recommend deleting/inserting the nodes or swapping the data. Both are very fine and functional options but I wanted to challenge myself and see if I could swap the nodes the "correct" way.

Ideally I would like to have a generic function that can handle all edge cases (moving to the begin, end and swapping random nodes). This has proven to be way more challenging than I expected.

I've experimented a bit with pen and paper and search around and I found the following discussion and example implementation:

- [Discussion about swapping in C](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/219236-double-linked-list-elements-swap)
- [Example implementation in C](http://ptspts.blogspot.nl/2010/01/how-to-swap-two-nodes-in-doubly-linked.html)

The issue I run into is that my `node1.next` and my `node2.prev` are swapped and that my `node2.next` refers to itself and not to the next node in the list.

The comment on the page of the example implementation specifically addresses this problem and mentions that it should not happen with his implementation.

I can't seem to figure out what I've done wrong. I guess I could "cheat" and force them to take the correct values at the end but that gives a lot of problems when the node is the first/last.

```
__author__ = 'laurens'
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
import logging
import copy

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class DoublyLinkedList(object):
    """This class implements a basic doubly linked list in Django, it depends
    on a Django model with the following field:

    id : PK
    prev: integer previous node
    data_field: Foreign key
    next: integer next node

    the prev and next fields don't need to be self-referencing

    When instantiating the class you have to link this class to a Django model
     and specify a data field. The data field can link to a foreign key
     or contain data
    """

    def __init__(self, doubly_linked_list_model, data_field):
        self.doubly_linked_list_model = doubly_linked_list_model
        self.data_field = data_field

    def get_node_from_node_id(self, node_id=None):
        """This function returns the node associated with a certain node_id"""
        if node_id is None:
            node = None
        else:
            try:
                node = self.doubly_linked_list_model.get(id=node_id)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                node = None

        return node

    @staticmethod
    def _update_node(node, prev=None, next=None):

        node.prev = prev
        node.next = next

        logger.debug('updating node: %s', node.id)
        logger.debug('node.prev = %s', node.prev)
        logger.debug('node.next = %s', node.next)

        try:
            node.save()
        except Exception as e: #Todo: specify this
            logger.debug('Error saving node: %s', node.id)

    def move_node(self, node1=None, node2=None):
        """
        This function swaps the position of node1 with the position of node2
        """

        #swapping two nodes!
        logger.debug('Swapping two random nodes!: %s, %s', node1.id, node2.id)

        # Swapping next nodes
        logger.debug('Swapping next node')
        tmp = copy.deepcopy(node1.next)

        self._update_node(node=node1,
                          prev=node1.prev,
                          next=node2.next)

        #Todo: Check if tmp changes or is stored as a copy
        self._update_node(node=node2,
                          prev=node2.prev,
                          next=tmp)

        if node1.next is not None:
            logger.debug('Connect the next node to node 1')
            node_next = self.get_node_from_node_id(node1.next)
            self._update_node(node=node_next,
                              prev=node1.id,
                              next=node_next.next)

        if node2.next is not None:
            logger.debug('Connect the next node to node 2')
            node_next = self.get_node_from_node_id(node2.next)
            self._update_node(node=node_next,
                              prev=node2.id,
                              next=node_next.next)

        logger.debug('Swap prev nodes')
        tmp = copy.deepcopy(node1.prev)

        self._update_node(node=node1,
                          prev=node2.prev,
                          next=node1.next)

        self._update_node(node=node2,
                          prev=tmp,
                          next=node2.next)

        # Connect the node before node1 to node 1
        if node1.prev is not None:
            logger.debug('Connect the prev to node 1')
            node_prev = self.get_node_from_node_id(node1.prev)
            self._update_node(node=node_prev,
                              prev=node_prev.prev,
                              next=node1.id)

        # Connect the node before node2 to node 2
        if node2.prev is not None:
            logger.debug('Connect the prev to node 2')
            node_prev = self.get_node_from_node_id(node2.prev)
            self._update_node(node=node_prev,
                              prev=node_prev.prev,
                              next=node2.id)
```

The `_update_node function` does nothing more than taking my input and committing it to the database; it can handle `None` values.

`get_node_from_node_id` takes an integer as input and returns the node object associated with it. I use it so that I don't have to work with self-referencing foreign keys (is that the correct term?) in the database, for now I would like to continue working this way. Once I have this working I'll move on to fixing it in the database in the correct way.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that others can actually run.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I've added the minimal example as requested!

Answer (score 1):

tip: I get answers *much* more quickly when I provide [a minimal, complete, verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), also known as a [short, self-contained, compilable example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/).

Your example code fails to demonstrate the problem, making it impossible for us to help you.
Please make it easy for us to help you.

I ran your example code, but I didn't see any output.

> The issue I run into is that ... that my node2.next refers to itself and
>   not to the next node in the list.

Why is node2.next referring to node2 a problem?

As far as I can tell, the part of the code you gave us so far works fine.

Some of the most difficult debugging sessions I've ever had ended only when I realized that everything was actually working correctly, that the "bug" I thought I was hunting didn't actually exist.

Yes, there is an intermediate step halfway through the algorithm where a node refers to itself, which may seem obviously wrong.

But then the second half of the algorithm makes further changes.
By the time the algorithm finishes,

- the "next" chain correctly runs all the way from the beginning to the end, and
- the "forward" chain correctly runs in the reverse order as the "next" chain, from the end to the beginning, and
- the order of those chains is similar to the original order, except that node1 and node2 have swapped logical position (but are still in the same physical position).
- Every node points to 2 *other* nodes (or to the NULL node), never to itself.

Isn't that what you wanted?

When I ran the following test script, I get lots of output --
but I don't see any problems in the output.
(I used a simple array with integer indexes rather than true pointers or references to make the code shorter and easier to debug compared to a SQL database).

Would you mind pointing out which particular line of output is not what you expected, and spelling out what you expected that line of output to actually say?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610889/trying-to-write-a-swap-position-function-for-a-doubly-linked-list
# Is this the shortest possible program that exhibits the bug?
# Before running this probram, you may need to install
#     sudo apt-get install python-django
# 2015-03-12: David added some test scaffolding
# 2014-07-07: Laurens posted to StackOverflow

__author__ = 'laurens'
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
import logging
import copy

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class DoublyLinkedList(object):
    """This class implements a basic doubly linked list in Django, it depends
    on a Django model with the following field:

    id : PK
    prev: integer previous node
    data_field: Foreign key
    next: integer next node

    the prev and next fields don't need to be self-referencing

    When instantiating the class you have to link this class to a Django model
     and specify a data field. The data field can link to a foreign key
     or contain data
    """

    def __init__(self, doubly_linked_list_model, data_field):
        self.doubly_linked_list_model = doubly_linked_list_model
        self.data_field = data_field

    def get_node_from_node_id(self, node_id=None):
        """This function returns the node associated with a certain node_id"""
        if node_id is None:
            node = None
        else:
            try:
                node = self.doubly_linked_list_model.get(id=node_id)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                node = None

        return node

    @staticmethod
    def _update_node(node, prev=None, next=None):

        node.prev = prev
        node.next = next

        logger.debug('updating node: %s', node.id)
        logger.debug('node.prev = %s', node.prev)
        logger.debug('node.next = %s', node.next)

        try:
            node.save()
        except Exception as e: #Todo: specify this
            logger.debug('Error saving node: %s', node.id)

    def move_node(self, node1=None, node2=None):
        """
        This function swaps the position of node1 with the position of node2
        """

        #swapping two nodes!
        logger.debug('Swapping two random nodes!: %s, %s', node1.id, node2.id)

        # Swapping next nodes
        logger.debug('Swapping next node')
        tmp = copy.deepcopy(node1.next)

        self._update_node(node=node1,
                          prev=node1.prev,
                          next=node2.next)

        #Todo: Check if tmp changes or is stored as a copy
        self._update_node(node=node2,
                          prev=node2.prev,
                          next=tmp)

        if node1.next is not None:
            logger.debug('Connect the next node to node 1')
            node_next = self.get_node_from_node_id(node1.next)
            self._update_node(node=node_next,
                              prev=node1.id,
                              next=node_next.next)

        if node2.next is not None:
            logger.debug('Connect the next node to node 2')
            node_next = self.get_node_from_node_id(node2.next)
            self._update_node(node=node_next,
                              prev=node2.id,
                              next=node_next.next)

        logger.debug('Swap prev nodes')
        tmp = copy.deepcopy(node1.prev)

        self._update_node(node=node1,
                          prev=node2.prev,
                          next=node1.next)

        self._update_node(node=node2,
                          prev=tmp,
                          next=node2.next)

        # Connect the node before node1 to node 1
        if node1.prev is not None:
            logger.debug('Connect the prev to node 1')
            node_prev = self.get_node_from_node_id(node1.prev)
            self._update_node(node=node_prev,
                              prev=node_prev.prev,
                              next=node1.id)

        # Connect the node before node2 to node 2
        if node2.prev is not None:
            logger.debug('Connect the prev to node 2')
            node_prev = self.get_node_from_node_id(node2.prev)
            self._update_node(node=node_prev,
                              prev=node_prev.prev,
                              next=node2.id)


global_test_array = []
obfuscation = 0xaa

class trivial_test_node_class(object):
    def __init__(self, prev, id, next, data):
        print "initializing test class."
        # self.stuff = [ ["first", 0, 1], ["second", 0, 1] ]
        self.id = id
        self.prev = prev
        self.next = next
        self.data = data
    def something(self):
        print "something"
    def save(self):
        id = self.id
        global_test_array[id] = self
    def __repr__(self):
        # print self.prev, self.id, self.next, self.data
        the_string = "%s(%r)\n" % (self.__class__, self.__dict__)
        return the_string

class trivial_test_list_model_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "initializing test class."
        #self.stuff = [ ["first", 0, 1], ["second", 0, 1] ]
        self.stuff = [ 0 for i in xrange(0,10) ]
        data = 'a'
        for i in xrange(1,10):
            self.stuff[i] = trivial_test_node_class(i-1,i,i+1,data);
            data += 'r' # talk like a pirate day
        self.stuff[-1].next = 0 # use 0 as NULL id.
        global global_test_array
        global_test_array = self.stuff
    def something(self):
        print "something"
    def get(self,id):
        return self.stuff[id]
    def __repr__(self):
        # for i in xrange(1,10):
        #     print self.stuff[i]
        the_string = "%s(%r)" % (self.__class__, self.__dict__)
        return the_string

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # test code that only gets run when this file is run directly,
    # not when this file is imported from some other python script.
    print "Hello, world."
    trivial_test_model = trivial_test_list_model_class()
    print trivial_test_model
    testll = DoublyLinkedList( trivial_test_model, "data" )
    left_node = trivial_test_model.get(3)
    right_node = trivial_test_model.get(4)
    testll.move_node( left_node, right_node )
    print trivial_test_model


# recommended by http://wiki.python.org/moin/vim
# vim: tabstop=8 expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 :
```